# How to create a while loop that continuously detects if scraped data changes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website. However, I want to create a code that will continuously scrape the website and print whenever the data changes. If the data doesn't change then it remains the same. Basically, something that will mean I don't have to keep clicking run to see if the data has changed.

I tried doing a while loop but didn't know how to include the data I have received online.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theurl = 'xyz'
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)

soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, 'html.parser')

data = soup.find('div' , ( 'class' , 'sticky')). text

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this may get the job done:

```
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
theurl = 'http://example.com'
# first iteration
thepage = urllib.request.open(theurl)
lastsoup = thissoup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find('div' , ( 'class' , 'sticky')). text
print(data)
while True:
    thepage = urllib.request.open(theurl)
    thissoup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, 'html.parser')
    if thissoup != lastsoup:
        data = soup.find('div' , ( 'class' , 'sticky')). text
        print(data)
    time.sleep(30) # sleep 30 seconds before looping
```

Answer (score 0):

This script can get you started. Each 1sec the script will **scrape** the page and checks for a change. If there's change, returns old and new value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=2&col=5&base=10&format=html&rnd=new'

def get_data(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

def watch(url, seconds=1):
    soup = get_data(url)
    old_data = soup.select_one('pre.data').text.strip()
    while True:
        sleep(seconds)
        soup = get_data(url)
        data = soup.select_one('pre.data').text.strip()
        if data != old_data:
            yield old_data, data
        old_data = data

for old_val, new_val in watch(url):
    print('Data changed! Old value was {}, new value is {}'.format(old_val, new_val))
```

Prints (for example):

```
Data changed! Old value was 1, new value is 2
Data changed! Old value was 2, new value is 1
Data changed! Old value was 1, new value is 2
Data changed! Old value was 2, new value is 1
Data changed! Old value was 1, new value is 2
Data changed! Old value was 2, new value is 1

...and so on.
```

You need to change `URL` and selecting right HTML element according to your needs.